# How to stop the threads in Python when the main process is at the end?

Tags: python

I have theards in Python and I need to kill them when the main process is at the end. How can I do that?

**MY CODE:**

- first thread:

```
def run():
    Log.new_record(record_type="INFO", record_text=f"The webserver has been started. Server is running on port: {port}")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port, debug=False)

webserver_thread = threading.Thread(target=run, daemon=True)
webserver_thread.start()
```

- second thread:

```
def run():
    while True:
        #do something

thread = threading.Thread(target=run, daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

I tried the `._stop()` function, but this error occurred. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2r6D.png)

Comment: Set them as *daemon threads*, and they will automatically be killed when the main thread ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a global flag that indicates that the process should exit, which the thread then reads each tick to check if it should continue. If not, just `break` out of the loop, or directly do `while not do_exit:`.

```py
do_exit = False
def run():
    while not do_exit:
        # Do something

# start run thread and do something
do_exit = True
# now just wait for run() to finish
```

Comment: Can I do something about the first thread?